# MVC change ModelBinder unit test

Tags: unit-testing, data-annotations

to extend my validation I have created my own model binder based on following article:
http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/TheBeautyThatIsTheModelBinder

In my application I extend my Person entity like this:

> [MetadataType(typeof (PersonMetaData))]
>   public partial class Person { }
>
> public class PersonMetaData {
>       [CustomRegularExpression(@"(\w|.)+@(\w|.)+", ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid")] 
>   public string Name;
>   }

My global.asax looks like this:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //Change default modelbinding
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();

    }
```

When I call the create event for my PersonController and the provided email is invalid, the ModelState.Valid field is false.

Now I like to create a unit test for the create method:

```
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //Change default modelbinding
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();

    }
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for Create
    ///</summary>
    // TODO: Ensure that the UrlToTest attribute specifies a URL to an ASP.NET page (for example,
    // http://.../Default.aspx). This is necessary for the unit test to be executed on the web server,
    // whether you are testing a page, web service, or a WCF service.
    [TestMethod()]
    public void CreateTest()
    {

        PersonController controller = new PersonController();
        Person Person = new Person();

        Person.Email = "wrognmail.de

            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(Person, null, null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(Person, validationContext, validationResults, true);
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }

        ActionResult actual;
        actual = controller.Create(Person);

        // Make sure that our validation found the error!
        Assert.IsTrue(controller.ViewData.ModelState.Count == 1, "err.");
    }
```

When I debug the code the ModelState.Valid attribute is telling me that there is no error. I think that the registration of the DefaultBinder was not sucessfull.

How can I register my DefaultBinder in my unit test?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038430/how-to-unit-test-modelbinder-with-modelmetadata) question and Darin's answer. It`s the way to test model binder, might help you.